# Jira REST API v3 throwing 404 Error (Issue not Found) when issue exists

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

I am able to add a comment when using a specified ticket number, but when I pull the ticket number from getIssues with a jquery, the I am not able to add a comment, it throws a 404 error. I'm using the same credentials for it all. I am using python as my language.

I am expecting a comments to be added. I have similar code and comment_body that works just fine, but I have to introduce a ticket number and documentation link with each item of documentation through if/else statements if I go that route. So I'm trying to get this completed through the code below instead.

I've tried the following:
Stripping any excess space away, using the IssueID instead of Issue Key.

When I print out the ticket information, I get the correct key in string format.

I have the correct permissions for this

Code:

```
def add_comment(ticket_info_dict, jira_url, api_token, jira_username):
    """
    Add a comment to a Jira ticket with documentation links based on the research type.

    Args:
        ticket_info_dict (dict): A dictionary containing ticket numbers as keys and research types as values.
        jira_url (str): The URL of the Jira instance.
        api_token (str): The API token for authentication with Jira.
        jira_username (str): The username for authentication with Jira.

    Returns:
        bool: True if all comments were added successfully, False otherwise.
    """
    # Iterate through the ticket_info_dict to process each ticket and its research type
    for ticket_number, research_type in ticket_info_dict.items():
        # Set up the API endpoint for adding comments to the ticket
        print(ticket_number)
        add_comment_endpoint = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/3/issue/{ticket_number}/comment"

        # Encode credentials for authentication
        credentials = f"{jira_username}:{api_token}"
        base64_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()).decode()

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_credentials}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

        # Check if the research type exists in the documentation dictionary
        if research_type in documentation_dict:
            # If the research type is found, include the corresponding documentation links in the comment
            documentation_links = documentation_dict[research_type]

            # Create the comment body including the comment_text and documentation links
            comment_body = {
                "body": {
                    "content": [
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "content": [
                                {"text": "This documentation relates to this research type:\n", "type": "text"},
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "content": [{"text": "Documentation Links:\n", "type": "text"}],
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "paragraph",
                            "content": [
                                {
                                    "text": f"-{doc_text}\n",
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "marks": [{"type": "link", "attrs": {"href": doc_link}}],
                                }
                                for doc_text, doc_link in documentation_links.items()
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                    "type": "doc",
                    "version": 1
                },
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "key": "sd.public.comment",
                        "value": {
                            "internal": "true"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "visibility": {
                        "type": "role",
                        "value": "Service Desk Team"
                    }
            }

            try:
                # Make the POST request to add the comment
                comment_response = requests.post(add_comment_endpoint, headers=headers, json=comment_body)

                # Check if the request was successful (HTTP status code 201)
                if comment_response.status_code == 201:
                    print(f"Comment added successfully to ticket {ticket_number}.")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to add comment to ticket {ticket_number}. Status code: {comment_response.status_code}, Response: {comment_response.text}")

            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                # Handle exceptions related to the HTTP request
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                return False

        else:
            # If the research type is not found in the documentation dictionary, add a generic comment
            generic_comment = f"This ticket has a research type of '{research_type}' but no documentation links are available for this type."
            print(generic_comment)

    # Return True if all comments were added successfully
    return True
```

Getting the ticket info with this function:

```
def pull_ticket_info(jql_query, jira_url, api_token, jira_username):
    """
    Retrieve ticket information from Jira using a JQL query.

    Args:
        jql_query (str): The JQL query to search for tickets in Jira.
        jira_url (str): The URL of the Jira instance.
        api_token (str): The API token for authentication with Jira.
        jira_username (str): The username for authentication with Jira.

    Returns:
        str: The ticket number of research tickets. Returns None if no ticket is found.
    """

    ticket_info_dict = {}  # Dictionary to store ticket number and research type

    # Set up the API endpoint for JQL search
    api_endpoint = f"{jira_url}/rest/api/3/search"

    # Encode credentials for authentication
    credentials = f"{jira_username}:{api_token}"
    base64_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()).decode()

    # Set up the authentication headers with base64-encoded credentials
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_credentials}"
    }

    # Set up the JQL query parameters and specify the fields you want to retrieve
    params = {
        "jql": jql_query,
        # "fields": "key, summary, customfield_13810, customfield_13427"
    }

    try:
        # Make the GET request to perform the JQL search
        jql_response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
        api_response = jql_response.json()
        # print(api_response)

        if jql_response.status_code == 200:
            for issue in api_response["issues"]:
                ticket_id = issue["id"]
                ticket_number = issue["key"]
                research_type = issue["fields"].get("customfield_13427", {})
                research_type_value = research_type.get("value", "N/A")

                # Add ticket number and research type to the dictionary
                # ticket_info_dict[ticket_number] = research_type_value
                ticket_info_dict[ticket_number] = research_type_value


            # Return the dictionary with ticket numbers and research types as key-value pairs
            return ticket_info_dict

        else:
            # Handle errors if the JQL search request is unsuccessful
            print(f"JQL Error: {jql_response.status_code}, {api_response.get('errorMessages', 'Unknown error')}")
            return {}

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # Handle exceptions related to the HTTP request
        print(f"Request Error: {e}")
        return {}
```

Each time I'm getting this error:

Failed to add comment to ticket GCPS-9679. Status code: 404, Response: {"errorMessages":["Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."],"errors":{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the jira python [package](https://pypi.org/project/jira/)?

Here is an example that should work for you for adding [comments](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html#comments):

```
from jira import JIRA

auth_jira = JIRA(jira_url, basic_auth=('*your_email*', '*API token*'))
comment = auth_jira.add_comment('*JIRA_number*', 'new comment')
comment.update(body='updated comment body')
```

Comment: I'll take a look a this. Thanks for the recommendation.